# Callback to method in different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have models Group, Membership and User. Connected with a has_many :through association.
Route wise, membership is nested inside group.

What I want is that whenever someone joins or leaves the group (ie. on create or destroy membership), to initiate a check on the group to check what the dominating language is (this is an attribute in the User model) and update the language attribute in the Group model.

I have a method called define_language in the Group model which seems to work independently.

Now I need to call this method from the Membership model, I was thinking to do this with an **after_save callback**, but I'm having trouble **referencing it to the method in the (different) Group model**.

I put this method in the Group model and not the Membership model as I feel semantically it has little to do with the membership. Is this assumption wrong? How would I go about this problem in an efficient way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is :

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  before_save :update_group_language

  ...

  private

  def update_group_language
    self.group.define_language
  end
end
```

I can't see how this could work though :

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :group
   before_save group.define_language
end
```

The problem with that is that belongs_to is only evaluated by Ruby when rails is first loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, you just run in Membership.rb

```
 before_save group.define_language
```

And tadaa! It will call define_language in Group.rb model.

Optional you can add such to define the relation:

```
before_save group.define_language "id = #{group_id}"
```

Comment: This is not correct, it will throw error "undefined local variable or method group" and you cannot call self.group in a callback, so you need to wrap the call inside a method, just as shown in the answer from @cmrichards